# Como usar una variable u objeto, en varias class o activitys?

Tags: android

Mi pregunta es, como puedo usar una variable de una activity en otra, osea que esa variable pueda ser tomada (de cualquier forma) por otra class o activity, sin la necesidad de hacer `click` para enviar los datos a la otra activity, e visto muchos ejemplos pero en todos se requiere hacer `click` para pasar los datos a la otra activity,pero en mi código no me sirve, pues mi código se ejecuta en segundo plano sin interacción del usuario,ejemplo:
como haría para usar esta variable en otras .class.

```
public double getLatitude() {
    if (loc != null) {
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
    }
    return latitude;
}
```

---

Amigo Bruno, tu respuesta funciona, pero no puedo implementarla en este codigo, la probe en otra activity y funciono, no se porque no funciona en este codigo,no se si es porque esta class extiende de un (AsyncTask), o no se si tiene que estar detro de un (onCreate),en la otra activity funciona dentro del metodo onCreate, ACLARO: quien recibe el getter en este caso es una class no una activity, estoy mandando las variables desde una activity a una class, saludos

public class LongOperation extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {

        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("oskr.developer1024@gmail.com", "oscar1258");
        sender.sendMail("This is a testing mail", "This is Body of testing mail","oskr.developer1024@gmail.com",
                "oskr.developer1024@gmail.com")                   ;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage(), e);
        return "Email Not Sent";
    }
    return "Email Sent";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.e("LongOperation",result+"");
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
}
```

}

cree una GlobalClass,

public class GlobalClass extends Application{

```
private static Double longitude;
private static Double latitude;

public Double getLongitude() {

    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double LONGITUDE) {

    longitude = LONGITUDE;
}

public Double getLatitude() {

    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double LATITUDE) {

    latitude = LATITUDE;
}
```

}

hago el  setter con este codigo desde la activity que contiene las variables:

final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();

```
                globalVariable.setLongitude(longitude);
                globalVariable.setLatitude(latitude);
```

y el getter desde la activity que recibe:

final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();

```
    final Double longitude  = globalVariable.getLongitude();
    final Double latitude = globalVariable.getLatitude();
```

Comment: usa valores staticos o guardalos en el sharedpreference

Comment: O crear una variable global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es tener acceso a cualquier variable desde cualquier parte de tu aplicación sin necesitar de dar click puedes crearte una clase "ESTÁTICA", con variables "ESTÁTICAS", usando el modificador `static`,

Te dejo un ejemplo :

```
   public class Globals {

    private static String latitude;

}
```

Desde cualquier actividad solo as `Globals.latitude` y ya tendrías los valores agrégale los `getter´s` y `setter's`

Answer (score 1):

pues es fácil solo pon

para abrir funciones en varias activitys

```
public static void Abrir(){

}
```

Para abrirla desde otra activiy

```
NombredelaClase.Abrir();
```

para variables que se utilizen en todas las clases de las activitys

```
    public static class Abrir{
        public static int Variable;
    }
```

para utilizar las variables desde otra clase o activity es

declarar variable de otra clase

```
NombreDeLaClase.Abrir.Variable = 1;
```

utilizar variable de otra clase

```
NombreDeLaClase.Abrir.Variable = Variable a recibir ;
```